# Performance differences between LINQ ToDictionary method and Copy Dictionary Iterative Loop

Tags: c#, performance, linq

While trying to see differences between copying a dictionary with `ToDictionary` and copying a dictionary using an iterative loop, I saw a really big performance difference.
In the code below I have created `Dictionary<int, int>` and copied it with LINQ and Non LINQ way.

The Code:

```
public static void Main()
{
    const int originalDictionarySize = 10000;

    //////Creating Dictionary////////////// 
    var originalDictionary = new Dictionary<int, int>();
    for (var i = 0; i < originalDictionarySize; i++)
    {
        originalDictionary.Add(i, i);
    }
    //////Copy with Iterative Loop////////////// 
    IteraqtiveLoop(originalDictionary);

    //////Copy with LINQ///////////////////////// 
    CopyWIthLinq(originalDictionary);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void IteraqtiveLoop(Dictionary<int, int> 
     originalDictionary)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var dictionary2 = new Dictionary<int, int>(originalDictionary.Count);
    foreach (var kvp in originalDictionary)
    {
        dictionary2.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    var endTime = sw.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine("The running time of copy with iterative loop: " + 
endTime);
}

private static void CopyWIthLinq(Dictionary<int, int> originalDictionary)
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var dictionary3 = originalDictionary.ToDictionary(i => i, i => i);
    sw.Stop();
    var endTime2 = sw.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine("The running time of copy with LINQ: " + endTime2);
}
```

The Output:

```
The running time of copy with iterative loop: 00:00:00.0005765                                                           
The running time of copy with LINQ: 00:00:02.5989753
```

Why the difference is so huge? 
I did this experiment with other types:

`Dictionary<int, float>`, `Dictionary<int, MyObject>` - `MyObject` has 2 members, a `string` and an `int`.

In the other experiments there was a difference between the Linq and Non-Linq, but only with `Dictionary<int, int>` the time difference was so big.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the differences is that the "iterative" method passes the capacity to the `Dictionary` constructor, which avoids rehashing. Although LINQ implementation can perform the same optimization (currently the full framework implementation doesn't).

But the main difference which produces the big performance difference is that your LINQ implementation

```
var dictionary3 = originalDictionary.ToDictionary(i => i, i => i);
```

does not produce `Dictionary<int, int>`, but `Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, int>, KeyValuePair<int, int>>`!

That's because the type of `i` in both key and element selectors is `KeyValuePair<int, int>` since `Dictionary<int, int>` is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int, int>>`. And `GetHashCode` / `Equals` methods which dominate the operation (`Dictionary.Add`) are much slower for `KeyValuePair` struct than for simple `int` (not counting the struct stack copy overhead when calling several methods).

It should be this instead:

```
var dictionary3 = originalDictionary.ToDictionary(e => e.Key, e => e.Value);
```

It still will be a bit slower, but not significantly.

**Update:** As correctly mentioned by @2kay in the comments, the `GetHashCode` for `KeyValuePair<int, int>` returns one and the same value when `Key` and `Value` are equal as in your test, which is the worst case for hash structures like `Dictionary` and makes the `Add` (which checks for duplicates) operation `O(N^2)` (quadratic) time complexity and really explains the huge difference in performance in this particular test.

Comment: When run more times in a row (WinForms), sometimes the Linq version is faster.

Comment: Thanks! It's working much faster and I understood quickly my mistake.

Comment: `And GetHashCode / Equals methods which dominate the operation (Dictionary.Add) are much slower for KeyValuePair struct than for simple int`
This is wrong. They're really slower bot not so much to give that huge difference. The actual cause is that GetHashCode gives equal results for each KVP when the key equals the value. Which in turn resulting in a collision on each insert.

Comment: @2kay right, but only when the key/value are primitive structs/no overridden gethashcode (and the same type) which is why he didn't see it in any of his alternate tests.

Comment: Why Dictionary<int, float> ran Ok with same code: var dictionary3 = originalDictionary.ToDictionary(i => i, i => i);

The running time of copy with iterative loop: 00:00:00.0015454                                                          The running time of copy with LINQ: 00:00:00.0100062